# Git push node js on Azure linux fails, kudu wants to run dotnet command

Tags: node.js, linux, git, azure, kudu

**Push from local git to an Azure App Service git fails.**

This has been working well until yesterday. I really don't understand why `dotnet` is involved in the push execution in Azure when the App is running in linux. I'm running git from Windows Powershell locally and deploying to linux, git add and git commit works fine but fails in push. I have searched for similar issues but this is a bit different from the other issues I found here.

```
The error is from git push:
PS xxx_deploy> git push 
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 212 bytes | 212.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
remote: Possible reasons for this include:
remote:   * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
remote:   * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-/opt/Kudu/KuduConsole/kudu does not exist.
remote:   * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
To https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/xxxx.git
```

The files being deployed are `.html`, `.js`, `.svg`, `.txt`, `.css`, `.png`, `.ico`, some `.woff` fonts
The dotnet it is looking for is not in that folder, I have checked, but why does it need it for a node js deployment?

I have tried a couple of suggestions by googling including:

- Carriage return and line feed flags, 'git config --global core.autocrlf true', I tried both true and false
- I deleted the files in my Azure App's /home/site/deployments/tools/ as some suggested that deployment files might have been corrupted, it did not help.

I would appreciate some solutions to this as I can no longer push new changes to the app.

Comment: I am getting same error while deploying node server

Comment: Hi @loyoliteabid, See my answer, it is not an optimal solution, but it works

Answer (score 3):

#### Issue is Resolved

The issue is finally resolved after trying a handful of solutions.

My hypothesis, the problem stems from a change in platform version by Azure App Service. I can confirm this because I had saved a copy of the App Settings from the week before. The former version is PLATFORM_VERSION 94.0.7.109 and the new is PLATFORM_VERSION 95.0.7.554, applies to my App I don't know of others. This also led to some changes in the environment variables. The PATH for example was missing /opt/dotnet/2.2:/root/.dotnet/tools, the CLR version changed and, so did the NODE_VERSION.

It seems that this created a mismatch between the files already deployed and the new pushed files. Its most likely that Kudu-git stores some meta-data of the platform in its manifest, hence the failure to build a new push.

### For anyone that encounters this in the future:

To resolve the conflict, create a newui in your Kudu deploy URL, e.g. `https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui`
From this page, open bash terminal and remove everything inside your home directory with rm or open the file-manager and delete all files/folders inside home.
Do a new git commit and push, your App will deploy correctly. It seems this clears all your previous deployments. Works well for a deployment Repo, it will be a disaster if it were a source code Repo.