# Unable to deploy update a react app to app service

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service, vscode-extensions

I have a react app running on an app service, I have already updated the app multiple times through the Azure vsCode extension. Now if I try to deploy a new version the output window on the extensions gives out the next message:

> Error: Failed to get status of deployment.

And there is nothing in the deployment center logs on the app service portal.
The app service uses a Local Git as source so I tried deploying manually to the git building the app myself and using the commands

> git remote add azure "my Git Clone Uri"

> git push azure master --force

But this gives the next output [image]

And again nothing on the deployment center logs.

I used to be able to deploy my react app this 2 ways but now I can't. Is there any other way to deploy or to know what is going wrong with either the manual push or the VScode extension?

Comment: I think this problem can be related with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68783434/git-push-node-js-on-azure-linux-fails-kudu-wants-to-run-dotnet-command